# Making a textarea read only

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

The textarea html tag has an attribute named `readonly`, which doesn't work in the Ember `{{textarea}}` helper.  `<textarea readonly></textarea>` works, and `{{testarea readonly}}` generates an error.  Any easy way to make the textarea read only while using `{{textarea}}`?

Answer (score 4):

This is a quote from the EmberJS documentation for [input helpers](http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/input-helpers/):

> Using these helpers, you can create these views with declarations
>   almost identical to how you'd create a traditional `<input>` or
>   `<textarea>` element.

Both of these will work

```
{{textarea readonly="readonly"}}
{{textarea readonly="true"}}
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue is because you were only specifying `readonly` and not setting `readonly` to a truthy value

the way to force a textfield to be readonly

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="app">
  {{textarea readonly=true}}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can extend the `textarea` view and add readonly property to it:

```
App.TextAreaRView = Ember.TextArea.extend({
  attributeBindings:['readonly'],
  readonly:true
});
Ember.Handlebars.helper('textarea-R', App.TextAreaRView);
```

and in handlebars you can use this:

```
 <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="app">
   {{textarea-R}}
 </script>
```

Comment: the readonly attribute is included in `Ember.TextSupport` so you should not need to extend textarea to be able to bind to it. The issue was that readonly was not being set to `true`